# Javascript Object with fall through key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm interested in this scenario, involving an angular filter.

I have a column returned from my database which is a boolean, I want to return from my angular filter based on that value. Simple:

```
function importExportFilter() {
    return function (value) {
        var conversion = {
            "true": "Import",
            "false": "Export"
        };

        return allowable[value];
    }
}
```

That is nice and simple, however it doesn't deal with cases where the value isn't a key in our conversion dictionary.

Two ways to deal with it:

```
if (conversion.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    return conversion[value];
}

return "Unknown";
```

OR:

```
return conversion[value] === undefined ? "Unknown" : conversion[value];
```

Is there a way to modify the javascript object to basically allow this:

```
var conversion = {
    "true": "Import",
    "false": "Export",
    "*": "Unknown"
};
```

where `"*"` is just a wildcard. It's not an exceptional circumstance where there is an unknown value so `Unknown` can be used whenever there is no actual value.

I can't seem to think of any other interesting ways to do this. Obviously in a business environment I would always go with the first way to deal with unexpected circumstances.

However, I was wondering from a creative aspect, if there were any other interesting solutions to this problem?

Comment: You could use an array of strategies and use filter to get the first one that can deal with the particular `value` state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `||`.

It takes the first value if the value is truthy, otherwise the second value.

```
return conversion[value] || 'Unknown';
```

or another technique:

```
var conversion = {
    true: "Import",
    false: "Export",
    unknown: "Unknown"
};

return conversion[x] || conversion.unknown;
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that! Yeah nice easy way

Comment: I like that addition

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not a feature of JavaScript.

But you can always just write:

```
return conversion[value] || "Unknown";
```

This is similar (but not strictly the same) as the null coalesce operator in other languages such as C#, but this is in general, how you assign default/alternative values in JS.

Comment: In C# I would wrap the dictionary and put and indexer on that wrapping implementation, but like you said, in doing that javascript doesn't have that functionality